# Is it legitimate to reference an (unlisted) external scripted library or framework in a stack snippet?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

In StackSnippets, the dropdown options (for jQuery, AngularJS etc.) are not available for most third-party scripted libraries or frameworks.

> **UPDATE:** Ah. It turns out ***there is a button*** for third-party scripted libraries and frameworks. A button I never, ever
>   noticed. Thank you for the heads up, *@TylerH*.

I referenced an external library in my stack snippet question by including an `<iframe>` with a `srcdoc` attribute, to which I added:

```
'<scr' + 'ipt>' + [... SCRIPT URL HERE...] + '</scr' + 'ipt>'
```

Is that an acceptable way of referencing an (unlisted) library or framework in a StackSnippet? Should I be able to do it that way?

My question concerns the question I posted in February and updated yesterday:

[Is it possible to achieve this kind of presentation using conventional CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028407/is-it-possible-to-achieve-this-kind-of-presentation-using-conventional-css)

The question refers to a CSS post-processor library I am developing called **axe**. The purpose of the question was to verify that the presentational effects I was delivering through **axe** selectors couldn't already be achieved via conventional CSS selectors (or even via still-theoretical CSS Level 4 syntax and / or selectors).

To ask the question properly I needed to show what **axe** could do. Since, when I originally posted I couldn't figure out how to access the *axe.js* inside a StackSnippet, I linked to an external page - which I recognise isn't ideal.

Then, yesterday, when I was answering another question about how to generate CSS Grid syntax:

[Looking for CSS grid generator or configurator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250896/looking-for-css-grid-generator-or-configurator)

I realised how I *could* include my **axe** example in a StackSnippet after all:

- Include an `<iframe>` with a `srcdoc` attribute in the StackSnippet
- Add a reference to the external `<script>` to the `srcdoc` attribute

The fact that I needed to break up `<script>` into two strings  (`'<scr' + 'ipt>'`) made me wonder if I should even be doing it at all.

If the answer isn't:

> Yes, that's very creative, Rounin, well done, you can include the **axe**
>   library in your snippets via this method from now on.

my follow up question is:

> Fair enough. I understand. In that case, how *might* I include the **axe**
>   library in my snippets from now on (without including the entire *axe.js* inline)?

Comment: I did my best to clarify your question a little, by putting the actual question *up front*. Please correct any errors that I may have made doing so.

Comment: Yes, I see that you have re-focused my question. That's fine, Martijn, I'm happy to go with your judgement. You are vastly more experienced on SO than I am - and I have never really dipped my toe in the water of meta before! Ideally I would prefer not to have inline **axe** because I am constantly updating it and I'd rather continue with a DRY / SSOT approach.

Comment: Well, I see two issues here then: that you were able to include an external script to execute is really a *security issue*, which is why I suspect you are getting the upvotes right now. But I think your underlying question is more one of *how can I create a MCVE properly in my case*. Including `axe.js` (if it wasn't a security issue) as an external script is not really an MCVE.

Comment: For that issue, you really will want to find a smaller example that doesn't require showing off all of `axe.js`.

Comment: I suspected it had the potential to be a security issue, which is the explicit reason I am raising on meta. But, you are absolutely correct - my underlying question is: if this turns out to be an unacceptable way to create an MCVE including `axe.js`, then how might I acceptably create an MCVE including `axe.js` (in the same way that MCVEs can include jQuery)?

Comment: If your question is about **using** `axe.js` then that's fine, the actual code using the library will be in the stack snippet. If the question is about the *behaviour of `axe.js` itself* then no, that's not an MCVE then.

Comment: As for your question, you could have achieved the same example by including an animated GIF showing the intended effects. You should really also focus on specific aspects, specifically talking about your own attempts to achieve *specific* effects using CSS only, currently your question is too vague and too broad.

Comment: Just to clarify, this isn't a question about CSS. This is a question about whether it's legitimate to reference a third-party scripted library or framework via an `<iframe>` `srcdoc` attribute (since the jQuery tickbox option is not available for most third-party scripted libraries or frameworks).

Comment: I know, I was adressing the question you **linked to**.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you didn't just use `<script src="path/to/axe.js"></script>` in the HTML section of the snippet?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I had the same wonderment... answered below how to do that. Maybe OP just never noticed the button?

Comment: @TylerH - Probably but just pasting the script tag as-is works as long as it's an absolute URL, right?

Comment: @BSMP Yes, whenever you run the Stack Snippet it pulls that code and runs it. I'm not sure if any caching is involved, or if it pulls a fresh copy each time you run it. Obviously a relative URL wouldn't work because the Stack Snippet doesn't have access to your local directories.

Comment: "*In StackSnippets, the tickbox option (for jQuery, AngularJS etc.) is not available*" -- FWIW there are no tickboxes actually, only dropdowns.

Comment: @Abhitalks there are in fact three checkboxes in the Stack Snippet window.

Comment: @TylerH: Not for libraries though, which was the context.

Comment: Thank you, Abhitalks - I have updated _the tickbox option_ to _the dropdown options_.

Comment: It's no more of a security issue to allow people to link to external JS files than it is to let people write JS code in line that will be executed.  If there was malicious code in the target file, the user could just as easily have inlined the entirety of the code.  The simple fact is that you need to be careful before you hit "run snippet" on any SO snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally got to the bottom of this. The problem was not at all what I thought it was.

**The key issue was** `https:` **vs.** `http:`

En route to discovering that this was the principal issue and resolving it, I have dealt with the following issues:

**1) Button blindness.** I have never seen the button `@TylerH` pointed out. I was aware of the jQuery, AngularJS dropdowns but I almost never use the jQuery dropdown and certainly never use the others, so... I didn't see the button.

**2) Manually referencing to third-party scripts is *allowed* in StackSnippets.** (As pointed out by several of you above). I had tried linking to my external script before - just by manually typing out the `<script>...</script>` reference, as `@Mike McCaughan` points out. But it never worked. So I concluded (erroneously) that if an external script wasn't a pre-approved well-known library or framework, it *wasn't okay* to reference it in a StackSnippet.

> **But...** in fact I could have referenced my external script in a StackSnippet all along **if I accessed the external referenced script
>   via** `https:` (and not via `http:`) as pointed out by `@Ferrybig` on
>   the question page itself, after I posted here.

**3) There is an iframe srcdoc solution (hack?)** I stumbled across the `iframe srcdoc` technique when answering a different question and I was delighted to see that the same technique would enable me to reference my external script in a StackSnippet. In fact, all it does is allow a StackSnippet to reference an external script via `http:` *as well as via* `https:`.

**Resolution:** I have moved the external **axe** script to:

https://rouninmedia.github.io/axe/axe.js

and I (and anyone else) can now reference it from within a StackSnippet without any problems.

Thank you for all your assistance, everyone (especially `@Ferrybig`).

Answer (score 14):

To address the question of how you *should* be doing it - Stack Snippets have supported linking to one-off/external libraries since (I think) day one of the feature's lifetime. Click the circled button below and you'll be presented with a textfield modal where you can input a library URL:

[image: External library link in Stack Snippets]

Provided your library is accessible from a website URL, you can link to any JS or CSS library or framework this way. It will include it in the HTML section with a `<script>` tag with a `src=""` attribute.

For example, if I manually linked to jQuery this way, it would show up at the top of the HTML section of the Snippet as: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>`.

As for whether your method is allowed... a moderator or employee would  probably have to speak to that, but I don't see why it wouldn't be, at first glance. It might be a security risk.

Comment: Wait. I have seen this window for the first time. Because of this, I found the button for it in the editor. Meta teaches something every day :D

Comment: Let me add though you should only link to scripts that will **stay around unmodified**.  Yea, I know it's a pipe dream to believe most users will think through it enough to do that. The problem is If you link to some personal server then either modify your external script or take it down your snippet stops working and becomes useless. SO is supposed to be reference so your snippet needs to keep working past the time you personally got an answer.